# Como fazer uma operação de subtração entre duas colunas de um dataframe e depois somar o resultado com uma outra coluna?

Tags: python

Tenho este código:

```
dados_train = pd.read_csv('arquivo.csv', delimiter=",")
y = ((dados_train.pop('col_name1') - dados_train.pop('col_name2')) + (dados_train.pop('col_name2')
```

Quando eu tento executar só assim:

```
y = (dados_train.pop('col_name1') - dados_train.pop('col_name2')
```

Dá certo!

Mas quando tento assim:

```
y = ((dados_train.pop('col_name1') - dados_train.pop('col_name2')) + (dados_train.pop('col_name2')
```

Dá erro!

Por que isso acontece? Alguém saberia uma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o método [list.pop()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop) remove um objeto da última posição da lista e a retorna ao usuário. Da forma como foi apresentada, acredito que a lista tenha dois elementos apenas.

tente acessar usando colchetes:

```
y = (dados_train['col_name1'] - dados_train['col_name2'] + dados_train['col_name2'])
```

Adendo: você se esqueceu de fechar um dos pares de parênteses. Eu o fechei no exemplo, mas esse pode ser o problema na sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado Arthur! Bem isto mesmo! Agora deu certo!

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: Você só pode marcar uma resposta como **aceita**, mas, se desejar, pode votar em todas as que achar que solucionaram o problema. Sinta-se à vontade

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza o pop ele apaga o valor da variável, então na segunda vez que você usa na verdade não há valor nele

você pode fazer assim

```
y = (dados_train['col_name1'] - dados_train['col_name2']) + dados_train['col_name2']
```

caso utilize em dicionario, tem a opção do `get`, não sei se se o `dados_train` esta recebendo um dicionario, mas se estive pode utilizar assim

```
y = (dados_train.get('col_name1') - dados_train.get('col_name2')) + dados_train.get('col_name2')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme! Deu certo!

Comment: Nada, qualquer duvida fique a vontade.